# Python:How can i get all the elements in a list before the longest element?

Tags: python, list

I have a list, e.g.

```
l = ['abc34','def987','ghij','klmno','pqrstuvwxyz1234567','98765','43','210abc']
```

How can I get all the elements in the list before the occurrance of the longest element and not the ones that come after?

Comment: BTW you should not name your list `list` since it will shadow a builtin.

Comment: and you should not name it `l` because it looks like `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
lst = ['abc34','def987','ghij','klmno','pqrstuvwxyz1234567','98765','43','210abc']
idx, maxLenStr = max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x:len(x[1]))
sublist = lst[:idx]
```

It only iterates through the list *once* for determining the maximum length, whereas using `max()` and then `index()` iterates *twice* over all the elements. It also stores the string with the maximum length in `maxLenStr` and the index where it was found in `idx`, just in case.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I actually think my solution is faster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742112/timing-functions/8742370 ;)

Answer (score 9):

This is one way:

```
l = ['abc34','def987','ghij','klmno','pqrstuvwxyz1234567','98765','43','210abc']
new_list = l[:l.index(max(l, key=len))]
```

Comment: beauty is in the eye of the beholder, i find it quite nice  :)