# Timing functions

Tags: python, time

Warning, this is a bit recursive ;)

I answered this question: [Python:How can i get all the elements in a list before the longest element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740018/pythonhow-can-i-get-all-the-elements-in-a-list-before-the-longest-element/8740093)

And after I submitted there where another answer that should be faster (the author thought, and so did I). I tried to time the different solutions but the solution that should be slower was actually faster. This made me think there is something wrong with my code. Or is it?

```
import string
import random
import time

def solution1(lst):
  return lst[:lst.index(max(lst, key=len))]

def solution2(lst):
  idx, maxLenStr = max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x:len(x[1]))
  return lst[:idx]

# Create a 100000 elements long list that contains
# random data and random element length
lst = []
for i in range(100000):
  s = "".join([random.choice(string.letters+string.digits) for x in range(1, random.randint(1,50))])
  lst.append(s)

# Time the first solution
start = time.time()
solution1(lst)
print 'Time for solution1', (time.time() - start)

# Time the second solution
start = time.time()
solution2(lst)
print 'Time for solution2', (time.time() - start)
```

## Update

Before anyone mentions why I put this is as a new question. The question is more about me learning how to measure execution time...

Comment: these two functions do not return the same type of object

Comment: Fixed it. But that even makes my code faster... And I still thought solution2 shoud be faster..

Comment: In any case, benchmarking should be done with `timeit`. It won't necessarily make one faster than the other, but it should give more reliable timings (chooses the most precise time function, runs multiple times to catch outliars) and is easier to use to boot.

Comment: @NiclasNilsson, You can use timeit. I think it is more elegant than timing it this way and judging performance

Comment: Okey. Thanks, try that next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda is costing dearer in the second solution.

I profiled both the codes and by the profile data, it looks, the first solution is faster

As the [wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Re-map_Functions_at_runtime) would say function call is costly and in the second solution, the lambda and the len function calls are making it run slower

Please note, I have trimmed down the list to a length of 1000 elements

```
>>> cProfile.run('solution1(lst)')
         5 function calls in 0.000 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <pyshell#305>:1(solution1)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {max}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'index' of 'list' objects}


>>> cProfile.run('solution2(lst)')
         2004 function calls in 0.012 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.012    0.012 <pyshell#306>:1(solution2)
     1000    0.006    0.000    0.009    0.000 <pyshell#306>:2(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.012    0.012 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {len}
        1    0.003    0.003    0.012    0.012 {max}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: I would like to accept all answers because they are valuable. But I can only choose one and I think this was the best explanation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems first version is making many less calls than the second one.

btw, This is probably another example of how idiomatic, simple code is often also the faster one in Python

```
>>> dis.dis(solution1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (lst)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (lst)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                0 (index)
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (max)
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (lst)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 ('key')
             18 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (len)
             21 CALL_FUNCTION          257
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             27 SLICE+2             
             28 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(solution2)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (max)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (enumerate)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (lst)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 ('key')
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object <lambda> at 000000000422BEB8, file "<input>", line 2>)
             18 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             21 CALL_FUNCTION          257
             24 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             27 STORE_FAST               1 (idx)
             30 STORE_FAST               2 (maxLenStr)

  3          33 LOAD_FAST                0 (lst)
             36 LOAD_FAST                1 (idx)
             39 SLICE+2             
             40 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. The called functions take far more time, for any reasonably big data.

Comment: @zch sorry I dont get it, could you explain your comment?

Comment: All the instructions are called only once per test. Running time of function `max` is proportional to length of input list. So, for big enough list (in this case not really big), running `max` would take far more time than executing other instructions.

Answer (score 2):

The timing looks ok.

`solution1` can be faster, because it doesn't use lambdas, so it doesn't need to call Python code in the loop. It does iterate the list twice, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: @joaquin Yes, you're right. I'm deleting my comment to avoid any confusion. Thanks for letting me know.